# Webpack unable to resolve a third-party module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I'm using [compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox](https://github.com/compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox) in a project migrating from RequireJS to webpack, and am wondering if the error I'm getting is in my setup or the module itself.

In my webpack entry point, I have:

```
require("angular");
require("angular-bootstrap-lightbox");
...
```

So, to attempt to satisfy those dependencies:

1. `npm install angular`
2. `npm install angular-bootstrap-lightbox`
3. `webpack`

Results in:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular-bootstrap-lightbox' in ...
```

If I comment out the angular-bootstrap-lightbox `require()` call, Google's AngularJS imports just fine, which makes me think the issue is with the third party module. If that is the case, what are they missing that they should add, and is there a temporary workaround?

Comment: Can you please show a webpack config file? Looks like you are not including your package into webpack bundle. Have you required this module in your code?

Comment: My webpack config points at `app.js`, and `app.js` is the file doing the `require()` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**angular-bootstrap-lightbox** doesn't have a main file specified in package.json. But there is index.js which requires the script. So you just need to specify it manually:

```
require("angular-bootstrap-lightbox/index.js");
```

You probably want to load css as well. So specify it similar way:

```
require("angular-bootstrap-lightbox/dist/angular-bootstrap-lightbox.css");
```

Comment: Could `"angular-bootstrap-lightbox/index.js"` be included in the webpack config entry list? `entry: ["angular-bootstrap-lightbox/index.js", "app.js"]`?

Comment: Yes, of course. I also recommend you to use two bundles - one for your app and one for thirdparty libs (for caching purposes)